# Reducing algebraic summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am a computer programmer by trade and am studying algorithm analysis...because i am masochistic like that.  Anyhow, I was looking at the solution for one of the problems in the book.  However, I am having trouble following some of the logic as it pertains to reducing an algebraic expression that is being expressed using Sigma notation.  I was hoping someone more enlightened than I am could break it down a little bit for me.  Thank you!

Here is the relevant text:

> This loop can be expressed as the sum:
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}1$$
>
> Reducing this, sum by sum from the rhs:
>
> $$\begin{align} &\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}1 =\\
>  &\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j =\\
>  &\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}j - \sum_{j=1}^{i}j\right) =\\
>  &\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{i(i+1)}{2}\right) =\\
>  &\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n^2+n-i^2-i =\\ &\frac{1}{2}\left((n-1)n^2
>  + (n-1)n - \left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - n^2\right) -      \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n\right)\right) =\\ &f(n) =
>  \frac{n(n(n+1))}{2} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12} - \frac{n(n+1)}{4}
>  \end{align}$$
>
> n=1 gives zero; and order is O((n^3)/3)

Here is the link

http://www.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.1

I am looking at solution 2-1.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Can you specify what is it that you don't understand or want help with?

Comment: In the link I provided, the answer 2-1 starts with a summation.  It then procedes to reduce/simplify that summation.  I am having some difficulty following the logic as it pertains to going from one step to the next in the solution. For example I don't understand how in the solution, it gets reduced from 3 summations to 2 summations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step that reduces from 3 summations to 2 summations says:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}1 =\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j$$

The first two summations on the left side are the summations on the right side, so this basically says

$$\sum_{k=1}^{j}1=j$$

And that says to add the number $1$ while $k=1,\ k=2, \ldots , \ k=j$.

In other words, add $j$ ones together, which obviously is $j$. So the reduction is correct.

There are too many steps in that link you gave to explain all of them here. If there are more steps you do not understand, you should specifically say which steps. Then we can help you more.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that.  This is my first post on Stack Exchange so I am not sure I followed all the protocols.  And I didn't know how to put the problem inline (seems like someone did that for me).

Comment: That makes sense.  I was thinking that the 1 was a k so it would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4.  But now I see that it is just 1 + 1 + 1 which equates to j. Sometimes it helps to get another set of eyes on a problem :).

Comment: @ssoutrs: The next reduction (two lines later) does involve $1+2+3+\ldots$, so it is easy to see how you could be confused. And I am the one who put the problem inline :) I've never quite copied that kind of text before: it was a good exercise for me.